# Scrapy: populate items with item loaders over multiple pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl and scrape multiple pages, given multiple urls. I am testing with Wikipedia, and to make it easier I just used the same Xpath selector for each page, but I eventually want to use many different Xpath selectors unique to each page, so each page has its own separate parsePage method.

This code works perfectly when I don't use item loaders, and just populate items directly. When I use item loaders, the items are populated strangely, and it seems to be completely ignoring the callback assigned in the parse method and only using the start_urls for the parsePage methods.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Selector
from testanother.items import TestItems, TheLoader

class tester(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'vs'
handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 200, 300]
#Usually, I only get data from the first start url
start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship','https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season']
def parse(self, response):
   #item = TestItems()
    l = TheLoader(item=TestItems(), response=response)
    #when I use an item loader, the url in the request is completely ignored. without the item loader, it works properly.
    request = Request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship", callback=self.parsePage1, meta={'loadernext':l}, dont_filter=True)
    yield request

    request = Request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR", callback=self.parsePage2, meta={'loadernext1': l}, dont_filter=True)
    yield request

    yield Request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season", callback=self.parsePage3, meta={'loadernext2': l}, dont_filter=True)

def parsePage1(self,response):
    loadernext = response.meta['loadernext']
    loadernext.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    return loadernext.load_item()
#I'm not sure if this return and load_item is the problem, because I've tried yielding/returning to another method that does the item loading instead and the first start url is still the only url scraped. 
def parsePage2(self,response):
    loadernext1 = response.meta['loadernext1']
    loadernext1.add_xpath('title2', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    return loadernext1.load_item()

def parsePage3(self,response):
    loadernext2 = response.meta['loadernext2']
    loadernext2.add_xpath('title3', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    return loadernext2.load_item()
```

Here's the result when I don't use item loaders:

```
{'title1': [u'2016 Rugby Championship'],
 'title': [u'SANZAAR'],
 'title3': [u'2016 Super Rugby season']}
```

Here's the a bit of the log with item loaders:

```
{'title2': u'SANZAAR'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season>
{'title2': u'SANZAAR', 'title3': u'SANZAAR'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship>
{'title1': u'SANZAAR', 'title2': u'SANZAAR', 'title3': u'SANZAAR'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship>
{'title1': u'2016 Rugby Championship'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR>
{'title1': u'2016 Rugby Championship', 'title2': u'2016 Rugby Championship'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship>
{'title1': u'2016 Super Rugby season'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR> (referer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season)
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season>
{'title1': u'2016 Rugby Championship',
 'title2': u'2016 Rugby Championship',
 'title3': u'2016 Rugby Championship'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Super_Rugby_season>
{'title1': u'2016 Super Rugby season', 'title3': u'2016 Super Rugby season'}
2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SANZAAR>
{'title1': u'2016 Super Rugby season',
 'title2': u'2016 Super Rugby season',
 'title3': u'2016 Super Rugby season'}
 2016-09-24 14:30:43 [scrapy] INFO: Clos
```

What exactly is going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One issue is that you're passing multiple references of *a same item loader instance* into multiple callbacks, e.g. there are two `yield request` instructions in `parse`.

Also, in the following-up callbacks, the loader is still using the old `response` object, e.g. in `parsePage1` the item loader is still operating on the `response` from `parse`.

In most of the cases it is not suggested to pass item loaders to another callback. Alternatively, you might find it better to pass item objects directly.

Here's a short (and incomplete) example, by editing your code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = TheLoader(item=TestItems(), response=response)
    request = Request(
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship",
        callback=self.parsePage1,
        meta={'item': l.load_item()},
        dont_filter=True
    )
    yield request

def parsePage1(self,response):
    loadernext = TheLoader(item=response.meta['item'], response=response)
    loadernext.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    return loadernext.load_item()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem.

Comment: Your awesome answer forced me to login to Stackoverflow to upvote you :)