# Load Item fileds with ItemLoader across multiple responses

Tags: python, scrapy

This is a followup question to accepted answer to question [Scrapy: populate items with item loaders over multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681269/scrapy-populate-items-with-item-loaders-over-multiple-pages). I want to use `ItemLoader` to collect values from multiple requests to a single `Item`. The accepted answer suggests that the loaded `Item.load_item()` should be passed to the next request via `meta` field in `request`.

However, I would like to apply `output_processors` to all collected values of a single field when returning the loaded object at the end of the crawl.

#### Questions

1. What would be the best way to achieve it?
2. Can I pass the `ItemLoader` instance over `meta` to next `request` without loading it and then just replace the `selector` or `response` elements in the `ItemLoader` when adding the values or xpaths from the next response?

Example:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    loader = TheLoader(item=TestItems(), response=response)
    loader.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    request = Request(
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship",
        callback=self.parsePage1,
        meta={'loader': loader},
        dont_filter=True
    )
    yield request

def parsePage1(self, response):
    loader = response.meta['loader']
    loader.response = response
    loader.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
    return loader.load_item()
```

Ignore the context of the actual websites.

Comment: @starrify, this question references your answer. It'd be highly appreciated if you could comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just pass the `ItemLoader` instance.

If I recall this correctly from irc or github chat way long ago, there *might be some potential issues* with doing this, like increased memory usage or leaks from reference handling, because you carry around object references of ItemLoader instances (and processors?) and potentially over long times, depending on the order of your download queues, by binding these itemloader instances to those requests.
So keep that in mind and perhaps beware of using this style on large crawls, or do some memory debugging to be certain.

However, I used this method extensively in the past myself (and would still do so when using ItemLoaders), and haven't seen any problems with that approach myself.

Here is how I do that:

```py
import scrapy
from myproject.loader import ItemLoader

class TheLoader(ItemLoader):
    pass

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    [...]

    def parse(self, response):
        loader = TheLoader(item=TestItems(), response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
        request = Request("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Rugby_Championship",
            callback=self.parsePage1,
            dont_filter=True
        )
        request.meta['loader'] = loader
        yield request

    def parsePage1(self, response):
        loader = response.meta['loader']
        # rebind ItemLoader to new Selector instance
        #loader.reset(selector=response.selector, response=response)
        # skipping the selector will default to response.selector, like ItemLoader
        loader.reset(response=response)
        loader.add_xpath('title1', '//*[@id="firstHeading"]/text()')
        return loader.load_item()
```

This requires using a customized `ItemLoader` class, which can be found in [my scrapy scrapyard](https://github.com/nyov/scrapyext/blob/master/scrapyext/loader.py),
but the relevant part of the class is here:

```py
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader as ScrapyItemLoader

class ItemLoader(ScrapyItemLoader):
    """ Extended Loader
        for Selector resetting.
        """

    def reset(self, selector=None, response=None):
        if response is not None:
            if selector is None:
                selector = self.default_selector_class(response)
            self.selector = selector
            self.context.update(selector=selector, response=response)
        elif selector is not None:
            self.selector = selector
            self.context.update(selector=selector)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried searching for the potential memory leak issue with this, but unseuccessfully. Could you give me any context in help to find out more?

Comment: @maivel, I hunted down the reference in the GitHub issues! https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/378 -- Looks like I might have implied more of that myself than there was (or more discussion happend on IRC back then). You'll have to debug things yourself if you want to be certain ;) -- see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html

Comment: nice one! Thanks